# iOS - friendlist with push notifications [architecture]

Tags: ios, facebook, azure, push-notification, background-fetch

I'm working on an app where users can send remote notifications (to run background fetch on the receiving device) to friends. The Facebook API can provide a friendlist. My question is, how can I send remote notifications to the specific facebook friend?

Currently I am using Microsoft Azure to store some basic app information - can it be used for remote notifications as well?

If there is a better way to trigger background fetches on a specific "friends" device (selectable by the user) please let me know.

Here is an image of what I try to build.

[image]

Thank you for any help and useful information!

Comment: Asking for specific recommendations on tools is off-topic. To answer your specific question, yes, Azure has notification support (just look at the mobile service offerings).

Comment: _“The Facebook API can provide a friendlist”_ – you will only get friends that are users of the same Facebook app as well.

Comment: Okay sorry, I didn't know that this is off topic. I try to get information on the architecture of this system - is there an appropriate community on stackexchange?
So I should build a custom friends feature, what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Azure Notification Hubs](http://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/services/notification-hubs/) (ANH), you can even use it for free to start with. Check ["Using Tags to Target Users" in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn530749.aspx) to get an idea of how it would work for your use case:

- Your app registers at ANH with a tag containing the user of the app, e.g. "user_saladFingers" (where "saladFingers" is the facebook ID of the user)
- When the user selects a friend to send a push notification to, you tell ANH to send a push notification to every device/app registered with the tag, e.g. "user_hubertCumberdale" (where "hubertCumberdale" is the facebook ID of the friend)

[image]

This tutorial explains in detail, how to send push notifications to certain users: [Azure Notification Hubs - Notify Users](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-ios-notify-users/).